# Converting this string to JSON object array using jQuery

Tags: jquery, arrays

I have a web service that returns this string via the `jQuery $.ajax()` call in the success callback:

```
[{"WaitlistID":1,"RID":45034,"CustomerID":2765957,
 "IsAdmin":false,"TruckSize":1,"Points":1},
 {"WaitlistID":2,"RID":45034,"CustomerID":2765957,
 "IsAdmin":false,"TruckSize":1,"Points":1}]
```

Unfortunately if I call `$.each()` on that value in the success callback it iterates over every letter in it, and doesn't treat it as a two element array, which is what I'd like.  I've tried the `makeArray(`) function but haven't had any luck, how can I convert that string into a JSON object array?

edit:

In response to the comments (thanks, everyone) I already do set the dataType to 'json', which is odd.  Here's the code in question.

```
jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: pagePath + "/" + fn,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: paramList,
    dataType: "json",
    success: successFn,
    error: errorFn
});
```

..so I'm not sure why it didn't work originally, but the parseJSON() bit did the trick.  Appreciate everyone's help.

Comment: Your ajax call is not properly configured. Use `dataType:json`. It will parse the json for you and give you an object as the parameter to your `success()` function.

Comment: There's is no such thing as a "JSON object".  Your string already is JSON.  What you want is a JavaScript object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [jQuery.parseJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/) to parse it:

```
var obj = $.parseJSON(str);
```

However, jQuery should already do this for you if the server returns the correct content-type. If it is not, you can specify jQuery to treat the response as JSON:

```
$.get("test.php", function(data){
   // callback
}, "json");
```

Or even better, use [jQuery.getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/).

Answer (score 1):

Try to parse with [jQuery.parseJSON()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/)!

Comment: Yes, just found that method and was returning here to answer my own question.  Thanks!

Comment: Better to use `dataType:json` in your `$.ajax()` call. You don't have to mess with `parseJSON()` that way.

Comment: @larryq Instead of `parseJSON`, you should add `dataType: 'json'` option to `$.ajax`

Answer (score 1):

What you have is returned is a string.. Try to set the `dataType` in `$.ajax` call.

```
$.ajax({
   url: blahblah,
   dataType: 'json',
   ...
});
```

Comment: I do have the dataType set to json, which made my original problem all the stranger.  Thanks for the assist.

Answer (score 1):

You have:

```
success: successFn
```

Does `successFn()` exist, and will it take a parameter? I.e., is it defined like `function successFn(myObject)`? If so, `myObject` will contain the object described by the JSON string. No parsing necessary.